# Array disappearing in Java when testing

Tags: java, arrays

This is a problem for school where we were supposed to create a method, findCommonElements that found the intersection of any numbers of arrays in O(N) time. We were only allowed to use Arrays so I wasn't able to use more convenient data structures like ArrayList.

I created my own test harness class and my tests are all working except the one where I use a method, initBigIntArray to initialize the arrays. I tested my initialize array function and it does indeed create the array that I am expecting so it doesn't seem to be a simple off by one error. The problem is that my result array to test against always shows up empty, even if I initialize the arrays to be all the same value. Any ideas?

CommonElements Class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class CommonElements {

    private static int comparisons = 0;
    public int getComparisons(){
        return comparisons;
    }
    public void clearComparisons(){
        comparisons = 0;
    }
    private void incrementComparisons(){
        comparisons++;
    }

    //workaround for not being able to use dynamic data structures
    public Comparable[] addArrayItem(Comparable[] targetArray, Comparable addItem){
        Comparable[] result = Arrays.copyOf(targetArray,targetArray.length+1);
        result[result.length-1] = addItem;
        return result;
    }

    public Comparable[] twoArrayIntersection(Comparable[] arrayOne, Comparable[] arrayTwo){
        int indexOne = 0;
        int indexTwo = 0;
        Comparable[] resultArray = new Comparable[0];
        //stops comparisons if one array is longer than another
        while(indexOne < arrayOne.length && indexTwo < arrayTwo.length){
            incrementComparisons();
            if(arrayOne[indexOne].equals(arrayTwo[indexTwo])){
                resultArray = addArrayItem(resultArray, arrayOne[indexOne]);
                indexOne++;
                indexTwo++;
            }
            else {
                incrementComparisons();
                if (arrayOne[indexOne].compareTo(arrayTwo[indexTwo]) < 0) {
                    indexOne++;
                } else {
                    incrementComparisons();
                    if (arrayTwo[indexTwo].compareTo(arrayOne[indexOne]) < 0) {
                        indexTwo++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resultArray;
    }

    public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Comparable[][] collection) {
        Comparable[] primaryArray = collection[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < collection.length; i++){
            primaryArray = twoArrayIntersection(primaryArray, collection[i]);
        }
        return primaryArray;
    }

}
```

TestHarness Class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class TestHarness {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        CommonElements testClass = new CommonElements();
        Comparable[] col1 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        Comparable[] col2 = {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        Comparable[][] test2DArray1 = {col1, col2};
        Comparable[] expected1 = {10};
        testResults(testClass,test2DArray1,expected1);

        Comparable[] col3 = {5,8,12,13,15,15,17,18,19,20};
        Comparable[] col4 = {0,3,5,8,15,15,20,25,27,31};
        Comparable[] col5 = {1,5,15,15,18,20,27,100};
        Comparable[][] test2DArray2 = {col3,col4,col5};
        Comparable[] expected2 = {5,15,15,20};
        testResults(testClass,test2DArray2,expected2);

        //this is the only one I am having problems with
        Comparable[] col6 = initBigIntArray(0,1000);
        Comparable[] col7 = initBigIntArray(1000,2000);
        Comparable[] col8 = initBigIntArray(2000,3000);
        Comparable[][] test2DArray3 = {col6,col7,col8};
        Comparable[] expected3 = {1000,2000};
        testResults(testClass,test2DArray3,expected3);

    }
    public static Comparable[] initBigIntArray(int start, int end){
        int size = (end - start) + 1; //10 - 3 = 7 but array from 3 through 10 has 8 values
        Comparable[] result = new Comparable[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            result[i] = start;
            start++;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void testResults(CommonElements testClass, Comparable[][] test2DArray, Comparable[] expected){
        Comparable[] result = testClass.findCommonElements(test2DArray);
        System.out.print("Expected: ");
        for(Comparable i: expected){
            System.out.print(i + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Result: ");
        for(Comparable i: result){
            System.out.print(i + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Pass/Fail: ");
        if(Arrays.deepEquals(expected,result)){
            System.out.print("PASS");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("FAIL");
        }
        System.out.println();
        int nValues = 0;
        for(Comparable[] column: test2DArray){
            nValues = nValues + column.length;
        }
        System.out.println("NValues: " + nValues);
        System.out.println("Comparisons: " + testClass.getComparisons());
        System.out.println();



    }
}
```

Here are the results I'm getting. Notice on the last one my result array is empty.

```
Expected: 10,
Result: 10,
Pass/Fail: PASS
NValues: 22
Comparisons: 21

Expected: 5,15,15,20,
Result: 5,15,15,20,
Pass/Fail: PASS
NValues: 28
Comparisons: 54

Expected: 1000,2000,
Result: 
Pass/Fail: FAIL
NValues: 3003
Comparisons: 2057
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the problem case your method `findCommonElements` finds an intersection of the three arrays, which is obviously empty:

```
col6 <intersect> col7 = temp_result = {1000}

(col6 <intersect> col7) <intersect> col8 =
= temp_result <intersect> col8 =
= {1000} <intersect> {2000, ..., 3000} = {}
```

Comment: Wow. I don't know why I didn't see this. I was looking at it completely wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's not that your array is disappearing; it's still there! You're just not looking in the right area. :)

It would appear that your

```
public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Comparable[][] collection) {
    Comparable[] primaryArray = collection[0]; <------------------------------Here
    for(int i = 1; i < collection.length; i++){
        primaryArray = twoArrayIntersection(primaryArray, collection[i]);
    }
    return primaryArray;
}
```

Only searches through the first section of the 2D array

```
    Comparable[] col6 = initBigIntArray(0,1000);
    Comparable[] col7 = initBigIntArray(1000,2000); <--- this
    Comparable[] col8 = initBigIntArray(2000,3000);
    Comparable[][] test2DArray3 = {col6,col7,col8}; <-- becomes test2DArray3[1]
    Comparable[] expected3 = {1000,2000};           <---related to test2DArray3[1]
```

Whereas, your array indice you need is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtCHp.png), not [0], as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtCHp.png) holds all values between 1000 and 2000, which is what you're searching for.

In short:

```
Comparable[] primaryArray = collection[0];
```

Only looks through and compares

```
Comparable[] col6 = initBigIntArray(0,1000); (stored in test2DArray3[1])
```

to

```
Comparable[] expected3 = {1000,2000};
```

Which are not the same.

Sorry for the bland imagery:
[image]

When you do your comparison in findCommonElements, you create a new array, and set it's value to the `[0]` array. When you compare in twoArrayIntersection, you're testing to see if they intersect, which they dont. Your expected array, as pictured, is the `[1]` indice portion of the 2D array.

So what ends up happening is this: you're calling twoArrayIntersection on those two marked arrays, connected with the arrow with the question mark.

None of the elements are common, so a new array is created with no elements in it, giving you no results.

Comment: Why would this be the case only for the arrays that were created with initBigIntArray and not that I initialized myself?

Comment: A lot of the actual testing of code runs through twoArrayIntersection function. primaryArray is tested against the next Array in the collection and the result is the new primaryArray and so on. If the above were the case then my other results should have failed as well, right?

Comment: Nope! Those will work properly because they're only referencing a single array. I'll update with more info, give me a few minutes. :)